How to format and display streaming Markdown data on the fly in TypeScript using Showdown?
Problem Description:
I am building a chat application in TypeScript that streams Markdown data from an API. The data is received in chunks, and I need to format and display it in real-time using Showdown.js. However, the streamed Markdown data does not format properly as it is displayed incrementally.
Issues Encountered:
Incomplete Formatting: The streamed Markdown data does not format correctly in real-time. For example, headers (#), line breaks, and lists often don't render as expected.
Real-Time Conversion: Since the content is received in parts, Showdown seems to struggle with incremental conversion.
Questions:
How can I correctly format and display Markdown data as it streams in real-time?
Is Showdown.js suitable for this use case, or should I consider an alternative Markdown parser?
Are there any specific techniques or configurations in Showdown.js that can handle this scenario better?


let accumulatedResponse = ''; // Accumulates chunks

for await (const chunk of streamChatCompletion(params)) {
    if (chunk.includes("[DONE]")) continue; // Ignore completion marker

    const cleanChunk = chunk.replace(/^data:\s*/g, '').trim();

    accumulatedResponse += cleanChunk;

    if (!messageBubble) {
        // Create the initial message
        messageBubble = displayMessage(chatWindow, accumulatedResponse, "bot", false);
    } else {
        // Update the message with accumulated content
        updateMessage(messageBubble, accumulatedResponse, "bot", false);
    }
}





public updateMessage(
  messageElement: HTMLElement,
  newContent: string,
  sender: 'user' | 'bot'
): HTMLElement {
    const converter = new showdown.Converter({ tables: true });
    const htmlMessage = converter.makeHtml(newContent);

    const messageContent = messageElement.querySelector('.messageContent');
    if (messageContent) {
        messageContent.innerHTML = htmlMessage; // Replace content with formatted HTML
    }
    return messageElement;
}



